# Proving the limit of an infimum of a function on an interval

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \underset{[x, x+h]}{\inf g} = g(x) $$

Where g is a continuous function.

It makes sense intuitively, but I don't know how to even begin proving this limit. Please help me.

Comment: Isn't $g$ monotonic?

Answer (score 0):

For every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x'\in[x,x+\delta]$, $|g(x)-g(x')|<\varepsilon$. In particular, this means that $$\inf_{[x,x+h]} g\ge g(x)-\varepsilon$$ for all $\varepsilon>0$. But we also know, trivially, that $$\inf_{[x,x+h]}g\le g(x)$$ as $x$ is in the range of the $\inf$. Thus equality holds, as desired.

Comment: Why is there a greater than or equal sign in the first inf statement? And how does g(x) - e <= inf g <= g(x) mean that inf g = g(x)?